# How to deal with long script tags in HTML5?

Tags: django, html

I'm using *django* for my web application and I'm suffering from verbose, long tags in HTML5.

Is there any way to line break the verbose tags like other languages does?

For example, in python, it will be far much easy to read

```
if a and b and \
   c and d and e and f:
   print 'line breaking makes me easy to read'
```

than

```
if a and b and c and d and e and f ...:
    print 'verbose expression without line break makes me hard to read'
```

So is there any way to break long lines in HTML5 tags?

For example, is it right syntax to do like

```
<script
data-main="{% static 'my-long-application-name/app.js' %}"
src="{% static 'my-long-application-name/require.js' %}">
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script data-main="{% static 'my-long-application-name/app.js' %}" src={% static 'my-long-application-name/require.js' %}></script>
```

And what is the most general way to deal with these verbose tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to have HTML element attributes that span multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851868/is-it-possible-to-have-html-element-attributes-that-span-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freely split verbose tag into lines, you know, [Humans should not have to grok XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-sbxml/) ;)

Also you can apply [django-htmlmin (HTML minifier)](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin) automatically on request to convert:

```
<script
data-main="{% static 'my-long-application-name/app.js' %}"
src="{% static 'my-long-application-name/require.js' %}">
</script>
```

To:

```
<script data-main="{% static 'my-long-application-name/app.js' %}" src={% static 'my-long-application-name/require.js' %}></script>
```